# Converting an integral equation into a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Let $a, b \in \mathbb R^n$ and $f, g \in L^1 [0,1]$. Assume for all $h \in AC[0,1 ]$ (space of absolutely continuous functions) following integral equality holds

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \langle f(t) , h(t) \rangle \; dt +  \int_{0}^{1}  \langle g(t) , h' (t) \rangle  \; dt + \langle h(0) , a \rangle + \langle h(1) , b \rangle  = 0        $$

My question : Can we simplify the above expression more? In the sense above can be equivalently written in the form of an ODE in terms of $f,g,a,b$?

Note that all functions are from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^n$. However we can assume they are just real valued function for simplicity. I was thinking about trying $h = \text{constant or exponential functions.}$

Comment: This questions seems a bit too elementary for MO; MSE would have been a better match. The basic idea is that you can integrate by parts in the second integral and then use that if $\int uh = 0$ for all $h$, then $u=0$ (it's a bit more complicated than that because of the boundary terms, but these can be handled similarly, by noting that $h(0)$, $h(1)$ are almost independent of what $h$ does otherwise).

Comment: @ChristianRemling  I already tried MSE but couldn't get suitable answer. $f,g$ lies in $L^1$ how can we use the integration by part?

Comment: crossposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3354286/195021

Comment: I think if $g$ is not essentially bounded, then $g h'$ need not be integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is elementary but let's state it. First one only considers smooth test functions $h$ with compact support (so that the last two terms disappear). If $F(x):=\int_0^xf(t)dt$, integrating by parts the first term gives $\int_0^1\langle (F-g), h'\rangle dt=0$ for all these $h$, whence $F-g$ is a constant, that is, $g$ is (has a representant which is) $AC$ and $f$ is its weak derivative. The initial relation then writes $\langle h(1),(b+g(1))\rangle +\langle h(0),( a-g(0))\rangle=0$ for all $h\in AC$, that is, $g(0)=a$, $g(1)=-b$. In conclusion, the initial weak relation (for a continuous representant of $g$) is equivalent to: $g$   is $AC$, $f=g'$, $g(0)=a$, $g(1)=-b$.

Comment: Thank You . Just one question for the part " $F-g$ is a constant, that is, $g$ is (has a representant which is) $AC$ and $f$ is its weak derivative" are you using a lemma or something?

Comment: Also In final condition $f =g'$, the $g$ is used might not be the original but rather a $AC$ representative of it. Is there any explicit formula that can write this  AC -$g$ in terms of our orginal $g$ ? Thanks for time

Comment: Yes, if an element of $L^1_{loc}$  (or even a distribution) has distributional derivative zero, then it is a constant (or constant a.e., if you see it as a function). The other point: for instance a canonical AC representative of $g$ is
$$\tilde g(x):=\int_0^xg'(t)dt+\int_0^1  \big(g +(t-1)g' \big) dt.$$
It is $AC$, its derivative is equal to $g'$ a.e, so $\tilde g$ and $g$ differs by a constant a.e. but the constant is 0 because $\tilde g$ and $g$ have the same integral on $ [0,1]$

Comment: Thanks. In the formula you wrote how do we know $g'$ exists almost everywhere ? If it does exist then I think we can write  the precise conclusion  in the form
$$  g(0)=a , \quad g(1)= -b, \quad   f(t) = g'(t) \quad \quad a.e ~ t \in [0,T] $$

Where I used the same original $g$ in question .  Am I right?

Comment: it's just the characterization of AC functions.

Comment: Yes, but $g$ may not be AC, it is just in $L^1$.   I'm looking for a condition in terms of $f,g,a,b$,  (as I stated in question) but what I understand from your answer is that the same given $g$ may not work unless we replace it with AC-representative of it. If that's the only thing we can say, I again asked you is there any  formula that can identify this AC representation purely in terms of $g$,  then you introduced $\tilde g(x)$ which is written in terms of $g$ but I see there You used $g'$ as well $g'$ may not exits at any point !! So that's why I confused . We are in a loop. Thanks alot

Comment: No. If  f,g are L^1 and satisfy your assumption, then g is AC.  "It has a representative which is AC" simply refers to the fact that elements of $L^1$ are not functions, but classes of functions. If g' in the formula bother you, you can write f instead. Anyway, I suggest to turn this question to MathStackExchange.

Comment: I already did, but  I didn't get any answer.  Let $g$ be $1$ on irrationals and $0$ on rational number. Take $f=0$ and $a=1 , \; b=-1$.   Then clearly the integral equality holds. but $g$ is not AC.

Comment: The characteristic function of the irrationals, as an element of $L^1$, is the constant ${\bf 1}\in L^1$ (=the class of all functions g such that g(x)=1 a.e.) it has a  weak derivative, which is 0. If you want to talk of point-wise derivative a.e., of course, you need to refer to a regular enough representative of this element of $L^1$. In fact the complete answer to your question is what I wrote; I'm saying math.stackexchange is more suitable for further clarifications and details on the definitions and elementary results.

Comment: Actually If I know individuals definitions like those classes. Yes I'm looking for  points wise characterization. By $g \in L^1 [0,1]$ I meant $g$ a measurable function with $\int_{0}^{1} | g | \; dt < \infty  $. I just want to make sure about final conclusion.  I asked in comments can your conclusions written in terms of point-wise a.e derivative rather than $g'$ which I assume you use this as weak derivative. I guess yes because you said $[g]$ admits an AC representation, let's call it $g_*$.  My question is ...

Comment: that can we conclude that 
$$  g_* (0) = a , \quad g_* (1) = -b, \quad g_{*}^{'} (t) = f(t)   a.e $$
?   Anyway Thank you for your time

Comment: Correct. Also note that your hypotheses are invariant for a.e. perturbations, so for a pair f,g just satisfying your hypotheses, without other assumptions, we can say nothing on the point-wise side.